# Why won't my script save cover art to mp3 files using Mutagen or Eyed3?

Tags: python, metadata, mp3, id3, mutagen

I'm writing a script to edit the metadata of an mp3 file. I have managed to get the genre, album name, year released, and composition artist all fully functioning, but it refuses to save cover art. My code is below:

```
from mutagen.id3 import ID3, APIC, TIT2, TALB, TPE1, TDRC, TCON
# Mutagen Version is 1.46.0
import eyed3

# Mutagen Function

def set_mp3_metadata(file_path, album_name, artist, year, genre, cover_image_path):
    try:
        audio = ID3(file_path)

        # Set the album name
        audio['TALB'] = TALB(encoding=3, text=album_name)

        # Set the artist
        audio['TPE1'] = TPE1(encoding=3, text=artist)

        # Set the year
        audio['TDRC'] = TDRC(encoding=3, text=str(year))

        # Set the genre
        audio['TCON'] = TCON(encoding=3, text=genre)

        # Set the album cover
        with open(cover_image_path, 'rb') as cover_file:
            cover_data = cover_file.read()
        audio['APIC'] = APIC(
            encoding=3,
            mime='image/png',
            type=3,  # Album cover front
            desc=u'Cover',
            data=cover_data
        )

        # Save the changes
        audio.save()

        print("Metadata updated successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {str(e)}")

# Eyed3 Function
# UNUSED

def set_mp3_metadata_eyed3(filename, album, artist, year, genre, cover_image_path):
    audio = eyed3.load(filename)
    if audio is None:
        print("Error loading MP3 file")

    # Set the metadata tags
    audio.tag.album = album
    audio.tag.artist = artist
    audio.tag.year = year
    audio.tag.genre = genre

    # Set the album cover image
    if cover_image_path:
        cover_data = open(cover_image_path, "rb").read()
        audio.tag.images.set(3, cover_data, "image/png")

    # Save the changes to the MP3 file
    audio.tag.save()
    print("Metadata updated successfully.")

# Usage
file_path = 'Music\Metadata\sample-3s.mp3'
album_name = 'Help me Stackoverflow'
artist = 'Your my only hope'
year = 2023
genre = 'HelpPlease'
cover_image_path = 'Music\Metadata\pulsar.png'
set_mp3_metadata(file_path, album_name, artist, year, genre, cover_image_path)
```

As you can see from my script, I have tried Mutagen and Eyed3, and I have also tried different mp3 files, different image files, different image file extensions, re-installing mutagen, Changing the image type from 3 (Cover art) to 0 (Other), Using Mutagen's Tags (shown below) and completely rewriting my entire script in case it was some weird typing error like an invisible character.

```
audio = MP3('example.mp3', ID3=ID3)    
audio.tags.add(
    APIC(
        encoding=3,
        mime='image/png',
        type=3,
        desc=u'Cover',
        data=open('example.png').read()
    )
)
```

I'm not sure what the problem could possibly be, so I'm hoping that you will.

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your code.
Executed locally with an mp3 and a png image.
It worked without any issues.

I did only change the file names and nothing in the code.
I executed it in a virtualenv using pipenv.

There may be some leftover libraries (do not take them into account) in pipfile.lock I only installed libraries: mutagen and eyed3

- Can you use a fresh/new virtual environment?
- Can you use new mp3 file, and a new png image? I suppose you can use the ones in the archive.zip as it already worked.
  And see if there are any issues with them.

Please see the archived file and see for yourself all the details.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_wUb7Qw1jfwYyBTyxpBN8wr0DYofbd9b/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score -1):

Fixed the issue. It wasn't loading on my laptop because of unknown reasons, but the file definitely loads on every other device. My script was fine, the media player was the problem.

Comment: How will this answer ever help anyone?